# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

My Application consist of 4 fragment as tabs being loaded inside a parent Fragment using `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The problem is when I run the app and press back and re-open the app I receive this error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1949)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1965)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:513)
    ...
```

the line of code inside parent Fragment is:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

and `ViewPage` and `Adapter` both are not null!!

I have to mention that all my `Fragment`s lifecycle is being managed  and the null issue is happening inside the adapter!, and the same Adapter is working fine when I use an `Activity` as parent instead of `Fragment`!!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After a lot of research, it looks like it is a support library issue:

> [Activity with fragment and ViewPager crashesh on configuration
>   change](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216157)
>     [Android Support Library issue 24.1.0](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218912)

I also found this answer, but it looks unusual adding a flag to my code:

> [Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()’ on a null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941263/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-os-handler-android-support-v4-app-frag)

I override the `finishUpdate` method of my `FragmentPagerAdapter` like this and problem solved for now!

```
@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    try{
        super.finishUpdate(container);
    } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException){
        System.out.println("Catch the NullPointerException in FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate");
    }
}
```

any better answer? please let me know...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I will try this fix until an official fix is released,

Comment: Glad that it helps :)

Comment: Worked for me... Thanks.

Comment: It's not working for me. Any better solution? Please let me know.

Comment: This works! Thank you for saving even more hours of work for this. :)

Comment: It happened to me ones but I can't reproduce it. How do you reproduce it?

Answer (score 16):

I have the same issue on my project. But it is my fault.

**WHY**

I call onBackPressed in a callback after the activity has invoked onDestroy();

Because the mHost instance in the FragmentManager is set to null after onDestroy() called.

and when call onBackPressed it will use the mHost instance again.

Answer (score 10):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//     super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
}
```

Override the `onBackPressed` in activity..
remove the super call : `super.onBackPressed`
and call finish.

Comment: are sure will it work?  I getting error sometime becz of onBackPressed()

Comment: Absolutely no idea why (technically) ... but it works!!! +1

Answer (score 4):

I know it might be late, but here's my stupid mistake I didn't see straight away:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onDestroy(); //I was calling the wrong super
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was caused by the reuse of `ViewPager` instance by different instances of a fragment. A solution was to null the adapter in `onDestroyView()` method of the fragment.

```
@Override public void onDestroyView() {
    mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Project demoing the issue and the solution [can be found here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114342#comment40).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was that I was re-using without noticing the adapter from the previous time opened.

I looked into the FragmentManager.java class that send the exception and on the very same line that crashes says:
"Must be called from main thread of fragment host"

my code was:

```
PagerAdapter adapter = MPageAdapter.getInstance(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

because I was using my PageAdapter as a bridge to communicate between fragments I used a singleton pattern. That worked well for me but once I repeated this structure in another activity I got the same exception. And the reason was that I forgot to destroy the singleton of my adapter class at the end of every use.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MPageAdapter.Destroy();  //I forgot this one, that makes singleton = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding `!isFinishing` in `onBackPressed()` of my `Activity`.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (!isFinishing) {            
            super.onBackPressed()
            // your implementation specific code here..
        }
    }
```

The issue in my case was through some code flow, my `DialogFragment` was calling the `onBackPressed()` of its parent `Activity` just after calling `finish()` which causing this crash.

Hope it helps if someone is still looking for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong activity reference to fetch

> getSupportFragmentManager()

Using the correct activity fixed the crash for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment **super.onBackPressed()** method and write **finish()** instead

```js
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//     super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
}
```

In my case this worked!

Comment: It may work but it's a nonsense answer because you are overriding the 'onBackPressed' behavior when you can easily call 'finish()' instead of using backpressed method